# Which view object should I pass to a function with a View object as parameter from menu?

Tags: android, function, view, menu

This is my function to which I should call to

```
public void myLocation (View v){


        MyMapSettings(MY_LOCATION);
        showMyAddressOnMap();
        drawGeofencesAround(MY_LOCATION, false);


    }
```

I am calling the above function from here :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.add:

        myLocation(View v); // I am getting error "Cannot resolve symbol". 

        return(true);
    case R.id.reset:
        //add the function to perform here
        return(true);
    case R.id.about:
        //add the function to perform here
        return(true);
    case R.id.exit:
        //add the function to perform here
        return(true);
}
    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
```

I want to know what kind of view should I pass to the function I am calling ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `public void myLocation (View v){` is a click listener so create a new function (name it as you like) and move the code of `myLocation` in a new function

```
public void getLocation(){
   MyMapSettings(MY_LOCATION);
   showMyAddressOnMap();
   drawGeofencesAround(MY_LOCATION, false);
}
```

and call it from anywhere like this

```
public void myLocation (View v){
     getLocation();
   }
```

and

```
 case R.id.add:    
     getLocation();    
     return(true);
```

or

if you don't want this whole thing then simply pass `null`

```
 case R.id.add:    
         getLocation(null);    
        return(true);
```